# CMake copy_if_different command copies the source file to destination, even if the source hasn't been changed

Tags: makefile, cmake, build

I am trying to use CMake's copy_if_different command to copy one tar.gz file to my folder, but every time I am rebuilding the project (event not with clean command), the command sees that it's executed always, even if the source file hasn't been changed. Here is an example below:

```
set(EXTERNAL_LIB_PATH_SRC "/home/pst/libs/void_lib.tar.gz")
set(EXTERNAL_LIB_PATH_DST "/home/pst/my_app/build/external_libs/void_lib.tar.gz")
set(UNPACK_PATH "/home/pst/my_app/build/external_libs/unpacked/")

add_custom_target(copy_libraries
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${EXTERNAL_LIB_PATH_SRC} ${EXTERNAL_LIB_PATH_DST}
    COMMENT "Start copying external libraries to ${EXTERNAL_LIB_PATH_DST}")

add_custom_target(extract_libraries ALL
     COMMAND ${CCRYPT} -d -k "some_key" ${EXTERNAL_LIB_PATH_DST} -c | ${TAR} -xf - -C ${UNPACK_PATH} -Z
     COMMENT "Finished extracting libraries.."
     VERBATIM)

add_dependencies(extract_libraries copy_libraries)
add_dependencies(my_app extract_libraries)
```

Am I doing something wrong here? copy_if_different seems that doesn't check the files at all, and the command is always invoked.

Also, Is there a way to avoid executing the "extract_libraries" command all the time, and executed it only if copy_libraries has been run?

Comment: Have you tried to run `cmake -E copy_if_different` in the **terminal** and check, whether it updates modification time of the resulted file? The check could be achieved by inspecting output of `ls -l /home/pst/my_app/build/external_libs/void_lib.tar.gz`.

Comment: BTW what do you mean by "the command sees that it's executed always"? It is correct that `cmake -E copy_if_different` is **executed every time** the target is built (this is the meaning of the **target** in CMake). But whether `cmake -E copy_if_different` **actually copies** the file in your case?

Comment: @Tsyvarev the timestamp of the dest file is not updated if the fils are NOT different, but the copy still happens, (I have measured elapsed time with significantly huge files).

Comment: ".. but the copy still happens, (I have measured elapsed time with significantly huge files)." - Are you sure that this time is spent on **copying** the file, not just for **reading** it (for check whether content is changed or not)? Note, that `copy_if_different` checks **content**, not a **timestamp**.